# How do I use GROMIT?

Tags: tar

I downloaded the [gromit-20041213.tar.gz](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/gromit/gromit-20041213.tar.gz) file, extracted it but now what? How do I use GROMIT?

Answer (score 0):

Gromit package is in [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gromit&searchon=names). You can easily install it by :

```
sudo apt-get install gromit
```